# screen flickers when i move the mouse over the screen. Position fixed z-index 9999

Tags: css, sass, screen, mouseover

Creating a popup.  Added after the footer, just to create it.   When i move the mouse the screen flickers.  if i add images i can't change the size or style them.

here is the css.  Using scss sass bem method

```
// enter code here

.popup {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba($color: black, .7);
    // z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML or maybe the hover CSS as well?

Comment: There are no hover attributes added to this section.  Just what you see.